# Display visibility in Argo UML

Tags: uml, diagram

How do I get Argo UML to display the visibility of properties and methods in a class diagram?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For a given project, you can cause the visibility to be displayed by checking "Show visibility" in the "File -> Project Properties -> Notations" dialog.

In order to make this behavior the default for new projects, check the corresponding checkbox in the "Edit -> Settings -> Notations" dialog.